# Using br or div for section break

Tags: css, layout, html

I've worked at few places and seen two different methods of doing a section or line break in HTML.

One way I've seen it done is like this:

```
<div class="placeholder-100pct">&nbsp;</div>
```

And the other is just using plain old `<br />`.

Any benefit to one over the other or would it be just a matter of style?

Comment: Can you provide some context via code example? Line-breaks inside of a paragraph would be (semantically) handled with a BR tag. But if this is for layout purposes you might consider using a clearfix class on the container DIV.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `<br/>` when you want a new line in a paragraph, like so:

```
<p>Hi Josh, <br/> How are you?</p>
```

This might be useful when writing an address:

```
<p>John Dough<br/>
1155 Saint. St. #33<br/>
Orlando, FL 32765
</p>
```

Using a div will automatically give you a new line, but if you want a space between two elements, you can use a margin on the div.

**Do not** use `<br/>` to get some space between two divs:

```
<!-- This is not preferred -->
<div>Hello</div>
<br/>
<div>Something else here</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for this.  It kinda became clear to me that <br /> is for the content and divs, along with CSS styling, is for layout of sections.  Guess it was a basic question I was asking myself but it was one of those moments that I wondered, "why am I doing it this way and how do others do it?"  Thanks again!

Comment: The spacing between the two elements will be determined by the line-height of the parent container, which is not necessarily what you might want. It was never meant to be used as a separator, but as a line break.

Answer (score 11):

A div is a generic container. A br is a *line* break. Neither is particularly well suited for expressing a section break.

HTML 5 introduces [sections](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-section-element.html#the-section-element). You mark up each section, not the break between them.

```
<section>
  <!-- This is a section -->
</section>
<section>
  <!-- This is another section -->
</section>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a <br /> when it makes semantic sense to do so. If all you need is a line-break, that's what it's there for. If you're trying to split sections of different types of content, then each section should be in a container of its own. For example, if you have an address where each line of the address would show on a separate line, it would make sense to do:

```
<address>
123 Main Street<br />
Anywhere, USA 12345
</address>
```

Comment: This makes great sense and goes along with what Steven said below.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One obvious difference is that `<br>` is inline element, while `<div>` is not.

So this:

```
<span>Some text broken into <br /> lines</span>
```

... is valid HTML code, while this:

```
<span>Some text broken into <div>&nbsp;</div> lines</span>
```

... is not, as you cannot place block elements inside inline elements.

Answer (score 3):

`<br>` has the disadvantage of limiting the size of your gap between sections to the line-height applied to or inheritted by the `<span>` it sits within.

In other words, with `<br>`, the size of the break can *only ever* be exactly the height of one line of text.

Definitely wrap *each* your "sections" in their own tags, and use margins to control spacing, if you want to retain any control over the spacing. The difference is not just in the semantics of markup.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to provide a break between two sections of content in the sense of a thematic break, then `<hr>` is the element you should use.

[W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element)

> The hr element represents a paragraph-level thematic break, e.g., a scene change in a story, or a transition to another topic within a section of a reference book.

It's also relatively straightforward to style these as needed as they can take whatever size you require. Note however that it is a void element and cannot contain content (although you can of course add a background-image to it as needed).